# Tensorflow - How to compute loss with policy gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

So I want to compute the loss, comparing my model's prediction with the validation output.

My code:

```
def _build_net(self):
   self.n_actions = 3
   with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
   self.tf_obs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, MAX_NUM, NUM_FEATURES), name="observations")

   self.tf_acts = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,),
                                  name="actions_num")

   self.tf_vt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,),
                                name="actions_value")

  flattened_frames = tf.reshape(self.tf_obs, [-1, NUM_FEATURES])
  init_layers = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=0.3)

  # fc1
  f1_layer = tf.layers.dense(
      inputs=flattened_frames,
      units=12,
      activation=tf.nn.tanh,  # tanh activation
      kernel_initializer=init_layers,
      bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1),
      name='fc1'
  )
  # fc2
  f2_layer = tf.layers.dense(
      inputs=f1_layer,
      units=6,
      activation=tf.nn.tanh,  # tanh activation
      kernel_initializer=init_layers,
      bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1),
      name='fc2'
  )
  # fc3
  all_act = tf.layers.dense(
      inputs=f2_layer,
      units=self.n_actions,
      activation=None,
      kernel_initializer=init_layers,
      bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1),
      name='fc3'
  )

  logits = tf.reshape(all_act, [-1, MAX_NUM])
  self.all_act_prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='act_prob')  


  with tf.name_scope('loss'):

      neg_log_prob = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
          logits=all_act,
          labels=self.tf_acts
      )

      self._loss = tf.reduce_mean(neg_log_prob * self.tf_vt) 

  with tf.name_scope('train'):
      self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self._loss)
```

**The way I am computing the loss:**

```
def compute_loss(self, input_data, expected_output_data):
        """
        Compute loss on the input data.

        :param input_data: numpy array of shape (number of frames, MAX_NUM, NUM_FEATURES)
        :param expected_output_data: numpy array of shape (number of frames, MAX_NUM)
        :return: training loss on the input data
        """
        return self._session.run(self._loss,
                                 feed_dict={self.tf_obs: input_data,
                                            self._target_distribution: expected_output_data})
```

**Problem: The _build_net works, but when i run compute_loss, I get this error:**

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'inputs/actions_value'
>   with dtype float and shape [?]
>
> [[Node: inputs/actions_value = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Now I know that I need to feed in something for `self.tf_acts` and `self.tf_vt`, but what if I don't know the values for them? What do I do for a workaround?

Also, is this the right way to compute the loss (for validation inputs/outputs) for reinforcement learning models?

Answer (score 0):

From TensorFlow perspective, there is no workaround to specifying values for placeholders. You can't ask it to compute `a + b` without giving a value for `a`.